# Get the height of a image no matter what mime type

Tags: php

I do not need to resize this image, all I am trying to accomplish is gathering the actual height of the $img just like a browser would interpret it. I allow a user to upload any image for some reason certain images won't return the dimensions, with just this getImageSize();

```
$img = $_GET['img'];


unction remoteImage($url){
$ch = curl_init ($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RANGE, "0-10240");

$fn = $img;
$raw = curl_exec($ch);
$result = array();

if(file_exists($fn)){
    unlink($fn);
}

if ($raw !== false) {

    $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if ($status == 200 || $status == 206) {

        $result["w"] = 0;
        $result["h"] = 0;

        $fp = fopen($fn, 'x');
        fwrite($fp, $raw);
        fclose($fp);

        $size = getImageSize($fn);

        if ($size===false) {
        //  Cannot get file size information
        } else {
        //  Return width and height
            list($result["w"], $result["h"]) = $size;
        }

    }
}

curl_close ($ch);
 return $result;
}

$outputheight = $result["h"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED :** you can use php function `imagesy()` to get the height of an image resource.
this method needs image resource not path.you have to do something like this:It should work for All type of images

```
$x="resultproces.gif";
$im = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($x));
echo imagesy($im);
```

see manuals here:http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesy.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php

Comment: That returns blank like when I try to just use the getImageSize();

Comment: method is not getImageSize() it is getimagesize()

Comment: I been reading up on this and based on the way the image is created the image might bury the actual height and width in the code depending on what kind of images were used to create the final copy. I do not know if this is true. I am wondering maybe if there is a way to pre-load the image and extract it using DOM?

Comment: I have used both it doesn't seem to work either way.

Comment: This works all I had to do is load the image into the cache after it was processed, then retrieved the image from the cache to use this function. Thnx 8-)

Answer (score 0):

use this... 
check the images type  with their extension
then switch case for .jpg, png and gif

$im = imagecreatefromjpeg(path to image); for .jpg

.......imagecreatefrompng(path to image); for .png

echo imagesy($im)

that's how I did at http://www.dpedit.tk

I am not on my pc . so I canot type much.